# Scala - Idiomatic way of creating a collection of types

Tags: scala, shapeless, category-theory

### Problem

Let's says that I have an ADT that look like that

```scala
sealed trait TT
case class A(...) extends TT
case class B(...) extends TT
case class C(...) extends TT
// ... lot of others
```

And I have this function that return true for of subset of `TT`. Let's say `A` and `C`.

```scala
def shouldIPublish(tt: TT): Boolean = ???
```

### Constraints

- the value `tt` we receive comes from a `SortedSet` that I can't really change. Here is how the function `shouldIPublish` is called : `tts.exists(shouldIPublish)` (`tts` is a `SortedSet[TT]`). It is erased.
- I would like that my code to be testable. Which is not possible with the solution I have for the moment. (see below)
- The code should compile for every `TT` type. If the actual type of `tt` is in a subset (i.e `A` or `C`) return `true` otherwise `false`.

### My imperfect solution

```scala
val shouldIPublishPF: PartialFunction[TT, Unit] = {
    case _: A =>
    case _: C =>
} 
def shouldIPublish(tt: TT): Boolean = shouldIPublishPF.isDefinedAt(tt)
```

I use partial functions here because the actual problem is a bit more complex. I use `orElse` to combine several partial functions together.

This solution is easy to reason about and simple enough. But,

- it does not seem very idiomatic. I means this tool (Partial Functions) does not seem to be the right one for the job (Testing if type is contained in a group of type).
- **I can't get every value defined for the partial function**. In that case it would be `A` and `C`. My unit test should fail when a new type is added to the partial function.

### Alternatives (I can think of)

#### Set of classes

Maybe the simplest solution. I could have a `Set` and get class with `.getClass`. It seems ugly though.

```
Set(A.getClass, C.getClass)
```

#### Shapeless Coproduct

Looked quite promising at first. Very idiomatic.

```scala
type ShoudIPublish = A :+: C :+: CNil
```

Unfortunately, I don't see how to test that a type is "contained" in `ShoudIPublish`. And I don't know if we can collect the list of all types (here `A` and `C`).

---

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Type class looks like a solution (if you know the type of `tt` i.e. specific subtype of `TT` at compile time)

```
trait ShouldIPublish[T <: TT]
object ShouldIPublish {
  implicit val a: ShouldIPublish[A] = null
  implicit val c: ShouldIPublish[C] = null
}

def shouldIPublish[T <: TT : ShouldIPublish](tt: T) = ???

shouldIPublish(A())
//  shouldIPublish(B()) // doesn't compile
shouldIPublish(C())
```

Standard type class is `shapeless.ops.coproduct.Inject`

```
type ShoudIPublish = A :+: C :+: CNil

def shouldIPublish[T <: TT : Inject[ShoudIPublish, *]](tt: T) = ???

shouldIPublish(A())
//  shouldIPublish(B()) // doesn't compile
shouldIPublish(C())
```

OOP-style solution would be to use a trait (if you can modify the hierarchy)

```
trait ShouldIPublish

sealed trait TT
case class A() extends TT with ShouldIPublish
case class B() extends TT
case class C() extends TT with ShouldIPublish 

def shouldIPublish[T <: TT with ShouldIPublish](tt: T) = ???

shouldIPublish(A())
//  shouldIPublish(B()) // doesn't compile
shouldIPublish(C())
```

Pattern-matching solution can work at runtime when you don't know specific subtype of `TT` at compile time

```
def shouldIPublish(tt: TT) = tt match {
  case _: A => println("A")
  case _: C => println("C")
}

shouldIPublish(A(): TT)// A
shouldIPublish(B(): TT)// MatchError
shouldIPublish(C(): TT)// C
```

or

```
trait ShouldIPublish

sealed trait TT
case class A() extends TT with ShouldIPublish
case class B() extends TT
case class C() extends TT with ShouldIPublish 

def shouldIPublish(tt: TT) = tt match {
  case _: ShouldIPublish => println("A or C")
}

shouldIPublish(A(): TT)// A or C
shouldIPublish(B(): TT)// MatchError
shouldIPublish(C(): TT)// A or C
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmyto. I updated my post to add details. 
1 - That's look promising using `Inject` but the type is erased so I think I can't have this kind of signature `def shouldIPublish[T <: TT](tt: T)`.  (see my edit above). And I would like my code to compile event when it receives another value. In that case it would return `false`
2 - I would rather not update the trait hierarchy.

Comment: @Dnomyar Since you have `SortedSet[TT]` all its elements have type `TT` and not specific subtypes. This means all compile-time solutions (type classes, implicits, shapeless...) will not work. So you will have to deal with pattern matching or reflection.

Comment: @Dnomyar I'm not sure I understand *"I can't get every value defined for the partial function", "I would like that my code to be testable. Which is not possible with the solution I have for the moment"*. Anyway you have to specify somehow what classes are in "true" family: `def shouldIPublish(tt: TT): Boolean = tt match {
    case _ : A | _ : C => true;
    case _ => false
  }`